# .NET Core SPA Templates - Passing data from MVC to Angular2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using the latest SPA template from https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

How can I pass a serialized object from MVC to Angular? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance you have two options. If you use server-side rendering, you can use the `asp-prerender-data` tag helper, otherwise, you can adopt the classical approach with data attributes.

For example (illustrating both approaches at the same time):

**Index.cshtml**

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"

     asp-prerender-data='@JavaScriptHelper.Json(this.Model)'
     data-serverData='@JavaScriptHelper.Json(this.Model)'>

     Loading...
</app>
```

**boot-server.ts**

Now in boot-server.ts, if you use server-side prerendering, you can access the passed server data via `params.data`. Also here you should pass your server data to the client side (`boot-client.ts`) along with the generated html. For example:

```
setImmediate(() => {
    resolve({
        html: state.renderToString(),

        globals: {
            serverData: params.data
        }

    });
    moduleRef.destroy();
});
```

**boot-client.ts**

If you use server-side rendering, the passed data (`serverData: params.data`) will be attached to the `window` object. For example, you could have something like:

```
interface ServerData{ id: number, name: string};
let serverData : ServerData = JSON.parse((window as any).serverData);
console.log("My data", serverData);
console.log("id", serverData.id);
```

If you have passed the object via data attributes, then:

```
interface ServerData{ id: number, name: string};
let root = document.getElementsByTagName('app')[0];
let serverData : ServerData = JSON.parse((root as any).dataset.serverdata);
console.log("My data", serverData);
console.log("id", serverData.id);
```

**JavaScriptHelper.cs**

Just a helper class serializing an object to string with some settings. There might be a smarter way, but.....

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public static class JavaScriptHelper{
    public static string Json(object obj)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Converters = new JsonConverter[]
                {
                    new StringEnumConverter(),
                },
                StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
        }
}
```

p.s. Before testing don't forget to run: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`

Comment: sending through attribute, and  I want to hide this data in web tools. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47786228/removing-script-or-div